# C# GUI with sql developer database

Tags: c#, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

---

I have been creating a database that will handle tutor and student information. Students will be able to access information about the tutors and the database itself will be able to track the students that come in for tutoring sessions (i.e. demographic information and major information as well as attendance). I have a good database created but now I need a GUI to go with it.

Last semester I programmed window form applications in c# with visual studios (2017) and I think this would be a great application to create a GUI with for this database. I am sure there is a way to connect my database to visual studio but I am not sure the commands that would be executed or the certain steps that take place inside visual studio (adding a file? reference?).

I am looking for one of two solutions. We have sql developer available on a school network that can be accessed via IP and student user/pass. I could connect the c# application to that database, but then it would only work while i am on the campus network (which is fine because thats where the application will be used). I cannot find any documentation on how to go about this, perhaps its not possible yet.

The other solution I foresee is creating a local database on my computer for the application which would work fine as well, as long as I can use the script that I have made already, if this is the case I just need to know how to connect the C# code to the local database (I am guessing to create a local database there is an option just like there is a windows form application, it would be a local database supporting pl/sql).

Anyways I would greatly appreciate any help given. If you can point me to some documentation or explain yourself IT would be a big help to me and my final grade (and the tutoring center).

Thanks all!

TL:DR Need a way to connect C# code to database either local or on school network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GUI:**
So first  off, in terms of what you should do for your GUI with C#, I would recommend WPF. It is newer and more supported by Microsoft than Windows Form Application.

**SQL:**
For your SQL connection it really depends on your type of database. I recommend you search the **NuGet** package library as there are connectors for almost every type of DB. I know .Net comes with a general connector, but personally with my MySQL DB I had the most luck with the MySQL connector in **NuGet**.

**More Help:**
Also based off of your tag **oracle-sqldeveloper**, I assume you are using MySQL. If you are a great C# guide can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL). I used this and it really helped in getting me started with MySQL & C#.

Comment: ugh I wish we were using mysql my prof is old school and we are using oracle. we are using the application oracle sql developer. However I'll still check out that link perhaps I can get some good information there. Also looking into the Nuget package, thanks!

Comment: @Fitz No problem! Let me know if there is anything else I can do for you!

Comment: What evidence do you have to make the statement "more supported by Microsoft..."?. Also, why do they need Nuget Packages to do what he needs? This is easily done with something like `SqlConnection`..Or if indeed Oracle, `OracleConnection` after adding `Oracle.DataAccess` ref

Comment: @FakeCaleb The fact is that WPF came out in .Net 3.0 which was after Windows Forms Applications and is using DirectX. DirectX is still heavily supported by Microsoft considering they have release updates for it consistently, and the fact that it came out after Windows Forms Applications shows that it is more likely to deprecate last as it contains newer technology.

Comment: @SeanMitchell Because something came out after something doesn't make it 'more supported' Winforms is currently supported on the latest .NET framework, making it a very viable option if OP already has skills in the technology

Comment: @FakeCaleb True, but WPF using DirectX which provides better graphics and has a lot more capabilities in terms of graphics than WinForms. booom. :D

Comment: @FakeCaleb so if I am using oracle database I can include the reference oracle.dataAccess? Will this give me access to the database on network (i am sure it requires I fill in the username and password information??) do you know where I can find some documentation?

Comment: @Fitz Sorry, we had a little disagreement (me & @FakeCaleb), but you can find documentation on Oracle and .Net [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedNETVersion/GettingStartedNETVersion.htm).

Comment: @seanmitchell Nuget seems pretty cool but it seems pretty extensive for the small database that I have (6 entities, less than 100 records atm). I also am still unsure how to actually implement it into the program, I see quite a bit of documentation for C# and mysql but connection information for oracle is quite limited EDIT: thanks

Comment: @Fitz no problem!

Comment: @Fitz if your question has been answered I would greatly appreciate if you marked so on my answer.

Comment: @SeanMitchell I am sure that it would work unfortunately the dba wouldnt give me the TNS listener information so I couldnt use this approach :/ thanks for your answer it did help and was the best given